# Authentication for service used applications

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, security, service, asp.net-web-api

When I create a Web API Service consuming by different platforms. Android Applcation, iPhone  Application and Asp.net MVC applications are consuming this service. But I wanna onlu authenticated users can use this service. Where should I put authentication mechanism? Where should I manage user sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You should write authentication mechanism on service layer only. You can store deviceid,sessionkey for a particular user in the database after successful login and can validate every service request with the help of this stored sessionkey and device id at service layer only. This is just a clue, you have to make your own authentication module.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple filter for authentication.
you can look into [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API)

Answer (score 0):

All the webservices which are being used in mobile and web applications must implement web service security other wise an attacker or hacker can access your service and cause damage there are many article on the security here is the link to an article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7062/An-introduction-to-Web-Service-Security-using-WSE

Answer (score 0):

You can implement web service Base64 authentication for authentication of the services.
It is easy to implement.

```
public static String RestHttpSetHeader() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String authHeader = null;
    if (getProfile() != null) {
        String emailPassword = getProfile().getEmail() +":"+ getProfile().getPassword();
        byte[] dataBytes = emailPassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String encoding =  Base64.encodeToString(dataBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        authHeader = "Basic " + encoding;
     }
    return authHeader;
}
```

And after receiving of Base64 token you insert it to web service header request from device.